# Diagnosing random crashes to black screen(Computer Still on)

Tags: windows

So i've been facing this issue for a few weeks.I just came out of an issue with my GPU where it was too clogged with dust, causing the temperature to hit around 100 where it would crash the computer, i realized the issue and now my temps are at 60ish and everything was fine for a while.

That may not be connected to this but i thought i'd share anyway.

**Age of Machine - Built Mid 2011**

1. i7 950 - Stock voltages and clocks
2. 12 Gb 1600 Mhz GSkill RAM
3. GTX 580 1.5 Gb Video Card
4. Corsair HX1000 Watt Powersupply
5. 128 Gb Samsung 830 SSD
6. 2 x 320Gb Samsung F4 in RAID 0
7. ASUS Xonar STX Audio Card

Currently what is happening is somewhat perplexing. Randomly while using my computer the monitor screen will go off, little to no sound looping will occur and the keyboard locks up(caps lock doesn't trigger the capslock light). That's all. No lights on my keyboard, no fan speeds going crazy nothing. The computer is on and its like nothing has happened, of course the computer monitor "has no signal" and it basically switches off.

I have been monitoring temperatures of CPUs and GPUs while playing games or anything and they seem to be absolutely fine. I have conducted a few memtest passes and nothing seems to be the issue with my RAM. I have also updated everything i can think of.

I can't for the life of me wrap my head around this. If there's any advice you guys can lend, i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: what's the machine's age? Mine is 2 years and it keeps doing exactly the same

Comment: I made it some time around 2011 mid year.

Comment: It appears to be a self-destruct mechanism, then. You know, fresh out of warranty.

Comment: My suspicion is the power supply, but i have very flimsy logic to hold that up. If i was forced to make a blind decision i'd blame it on ASUS' notorious motherboard

Comment: Mine is Lenovo. It could be a power supply because it seems to happen for me only when I'm running on batteries, never when plugged in

Comment: Oh you're using a laptop? Well in your case there's almost nothing you can do other than send it in for repairs heh.

Comment: or just back up important data and replace hardware at the last possible moment